# Porting xcos from 5.5.2 to 6.0.1

Tags: porting, scilab, xcos

Opening xcos drawn in 5.5.2 using 6.0.2 results in blank pages.

There are no special import functions I can find in the 6.0 help.   There are no white papers I've found yet on the scilab website.  I suspect that since 6.0 was a substantial rewrite that we need to substantially redraw our xcos diagrams to move from 5.5 to 6.0?   Can anybody confirm?

I expected a v5.5x xcos diagram to open up in v6.0x, i.e. lots of block diagrams and connectors.   It is happily opened by v6.0.2 but it is blank except from some annotations that got carried over.

Comment: Post your question on the users@lists.scilab.org mailing list. Register @ http://mailinglists.scilab.org/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=start_registration_page

Comment: It is really sad that Scilab doesn't assure backward compatibility.